# how to use PDF templates in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf

I'm trying to have a pdf template, where i can replace certain tags and print out a new PDF

I started by letting users write the text and use curly braces on stuff like `user.name` but the problem with this is formatting.
I can+t let users bold part of the text or use headlines, and then store that on firebase database.

so now i was trying to have a template pdf that the user can have in his phone/pc, read that file and substitute the tags with the data i have.

what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of converting html to pdf.

You can let the users edit an html template with pre-defined parameters you provide like `user.name` and set styles they want. After that replace the predefined parameters with the html template and use external library like [flutter_html_to_pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html_to_pdf) to convert html to pdf.

Comment: not a bad idea, do you have some idea of how this would look like?